# Can't put a inline tag inside of a html input tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a input tag like:

```
<input src="..."   title="<%= SomeResource.Label1 %>" />
```

It is not rending the text, it is rendering the actual value in the title attribute:

```
<%= SomeResource.SoeLabelInMyResourceFile%>
```

I tried single quotes and no change, what am i doing wrong?

It is suppose to render the title attribute as:

```
title="some text value stored in the resource file"
```

So the issue is the server tags are not being rendered, rather it is thinking that is plain text I want to display for the value of the title attribute.

**UPDATE**

The text renders just fine if I do this:

```
<td>
<%= SomeResource.Label1 %>
<input src="..."   title="" />
</td>
```

**But if I put the tags inside the title attribute, I get the error.**

Comment: Um, I'm confused. What do you mean by rendering the value? Is this a Label control that you're trying to access? What about SomeResource.Label1.Text?

Comment: Remove the space after the '=' sign and try again

Comment: @Phillip nope that wasn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1 Create service folder **App_GlobalResources** (Project -> Add -> ASP.NET Folder)

2 Move resx-files to this folder

3 Get access to data:

> In addition to programmatic access, ASP.NET 2.0 also introduces declarative syntax you can use to bind a named string to a property of a page or control. The syntax involves using the dollar sign ($) followed by the Resources namespace, the name of the resource file and the name of the string [see [Resources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx)]

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource1, String1 %>" />
<input runat="server" type="text" value="<%$ Resources:Resource1, String1 %>" />
```

**It works fine!**

---

Try it:

```
<input src="..."   title="<%$ Resources:SomeResource, Label1 %>" />
```

or

```
<input runat="server" src="..."   title="<%$ Resources:SomeResource, Label1 %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it work with an `<asp:textbox>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GetLocalResourceObject()`

```
<input src="..."   title="<%= GetLocalResourceObject('SomeResource.Label1') %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your input is marked as runat="server" ?
If you'll remove runat="server" title="<%= SomeResource.Label1.Text %>" gonna be work as expected.